# case_when in mutate pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems `dplyr::case_when` doesn't behave as other commands in a `dplyr::mutate` call. For instance:

```
library(dplyr)

case_when(mtcars$carb <= 2 ~ "low",
          mtcars$carb > 2 ~ "high") %>% 
  table
```

works:

```
.
high  low 
  15   17
```

But put `case_when` in a `mutate` chain:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = case_when(carb <= 2 ~ "low",
                        carb > 2 ~ "high"))
```

and you get:

```
 Error: object 'carb' not found
```

while this works fine

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = carb %>% 
           cut(c(0, 2, 8)))
```

Comment: Yes, it won't. Check the section on `case_when` [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/), and [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1965)

Comment: as described below, this issue has gone away with dplyr > 0.7.0

Comment: Maybe accept one of the answers, looks like this now works.

Comment: In case you want to divide a range into several intervals, it is worth considering using `cut` instead of `case_when`. `cut` has a `labels` argument which makes it possible to rename the resulting categories.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

As of version `0.7.0` of `dplyr`, `case_when` works within `mutate` as follows:

```
library(dplyr) # >= 0.7.0
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cg = case_when(carb <= 2 ~ "low",
                        carb > 2  ~ "high"))
```

For more information: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Comment: `dplyr` < `0.7.0` would benefit from an error message indicating that this is resolved in `0.7.0` rather than `Error: object 'carb' not found`.

Comment: For completeness' sake, you can add at the end: `, .default = "other"` as an "else" statement

Answer (score 22):

We can use `.$`

```
mtcars %>%  
     mutate(cg = case_when(.$carb <= 2 ~ "low",  .$carb > 2 ~ "high")) %>%
    .$cg %>%
    table()
# high  low 
#  15   17
```

Comment: sure, I'm familiar with the `.` operator, but it's not necessary for `cut`, `recode` etc...

Comment: @tomw  I was just answering based on the question you posted and as per Sumedh's (deleted post), the `case_when` is stilll on a experimental stage so some of the regular things that works on other functions may not work here.

Answer (score 8):

With thanks to @sumedh: @hadley [has explained](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/) that this is a known shortcoming of `case_when`:

> `case_when()` is still somewhat experiment and does not currently work
>   inside `mutate()`. That will be fixed in a future version.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, quasiquotation helped a lot. You can create in advance a set of quoted formulae that define the mutation rules (and either use known column names as in the first formula or benefit from `!!` and create rules dynamically as in the second formula), which is then utilized within `mutate` - `case_when` combination like here

```r
    library(dplyr)
    library(rlang)
    pattern <- quos(gear == 3L ~ "three", !!sym("gear") == 4L ~ "four", gear == 5L ~ "five")
    # Or
    # pattern <- list(
    #     quo(gear == 3L ~ "three"), 
    #     quo(!!sym("gear") == 4L ~ "four"),
    #     quo(gear == 5L ~ "five"))
    #
    mtcars %>% mutate(test = case_when(!!!pattern)) %>% head(10L)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  test
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  four
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  four
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  four
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 three
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 three
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 three
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 three
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  four
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  four
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  four
```

I prefer such solution because it allows creating complex rules, e.g. using `map2` with LHS conditions and RHS values to generate quoted formulas

```r
    library(rlang)
    library(purrr)
    map2(c(3, 4, 5), c("three", "four", "five"), ~quo(gear == !!.x ~ !!.y))
#> [[1]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^gear == 3 ~ "three"
#> env:  0000000014286520
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^gear == 4 ~ "four"
#> env:  000000001273D0E0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^gear == 5 ~ "five"
#> env:  00000000125870E0
```

and using it in different places, applying to different data sets without the need to manually type in all the rules every time you need a complex mutation.

As a final answer to the problem, 7 additional symbols and two parentheses solve it

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(test = case_when(!!!quos(gear == 3L ~ "three", gear != 3L ~ "not three"))) %>% 
    head(10L)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      test
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 not three
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 not three
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 not three
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     three
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     three
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     three
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     three
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 not three
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 not three
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 not three
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
data_2 = mutate(data, name = case_when(condition_new_var  ~ value, condition_new_var ~ value, condition_new_var ~ value))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -2):

```
library(dplyr) #loading the dplyr package

content150_fortified <- content150 %>% #creating a new variable
mutate(number_yn = case_when( #creating a new column using mutate
        number >= 18 & number <=25 ~ "no", # if number is "none", make number_yn "no"
        number!="none" ~ "yes"  # if number is not "none", make number_yn "yes"
        )
      )
```

Comment: Okay I'll try something different

Answer (score -4):

In addition to @akrun's answer above, be aware that the closing parenthesis for the `case_when()` **cannot** be put it onto its own line.

For example, this works OK:

```
mtcars %>%  
   mutate(cg = case_when(
      .$carb <= 2 ~ "low",  .$carb > 2 ~ "high"))
```

but this does not:

```
mtcars %>%  
   mutate(cg = case_when(
      .$carb <= 2 ~ "low",  .$carb > 2 ~ "high")
      )
```

Comment: Huh? Both work fine for me. I can't imagine that the _parser_ would have problems with something like this (as opposed to the underlying evaluator).