# Conditionally mutate columns by factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple dataframe and I wanted to transform the column `X` using `dplyr`, such that a constant value `20` is subtracted from all elements in `X`, if and only if `I==1`.

```
library(dplyr)
myData<-data.frame(
  I=as.factor(c(1,2,1)),
  X=c(4,2,3)
)
```

How can achieve this behavior. My first attempt was to use:

```
result<-myData%>% filter(I==1) %>% mutate(X=X-20)
```

But now I don't know how to merge `result` back to myData? I also tried `mutate_if`, but I'm unsure, how to use it.

A basic R alternative solution might be:

```
myData$X[myData$I==1]=myData$X[myData$I==1]-20
```

But as I said I'm looking for a dplyr solution:

Comment: Relevant post where OP wants to [avoid using ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162). Another relevant post, [using case_when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649533)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `if_else`:

```
myData %>% 
  mutate(X = X - if_else(I == "1", 20, 0))

# Or
myData %>% 
  mutate(X = if_else(I == "1", X - 20, X))

#   I   X
# 1 1 -16
# 2 2   2
# 3 1 -17
```