# Using list as input for case_when inside of mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

in short:
Can you use `!!!` splicing and a list input for `case_when` inside of a `mutate`, and how?

As mentioned in an answer to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649533/case-when-in-mutate-pipe) as of dplyr >0.7.0 you can use bare variable names inside a `case_when()` inside of a `mutate()`

Next to that, in the [help file](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) for `case_when` it shows how you can use a list of patterns and `!!!` like so: (patterns is the wrong way around, with general case first, but that is the case in the actual documentation and doesn't matter for my issue)

```
x <- 1:50
patterns <- list(
  TRUE ~ as.character(x),
  x %%  5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %%  7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz"
)
case_when(!!! patterns)
```

However, combining these approaches doens't seem to work:

```
testframe <- tibble(y = 1:50) #Switching to y so the x from earlier can't interfere

testframe2 <- testframe %>% 
  mutate(
    fizzbuzz = case_when(
      y %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
      y %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
      y %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
      TRUE ~ as.character(y)
    )
  )

patterns <- list(
  y %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  y %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  y %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ as.character(y)
)

testframe3 <- testframe %>% 
  mutate(
    fizzbuzz = case_when(
      !!!(patterns)
    )
  )
```

testframe2 will work fine, whilst testframe3 gives the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'y' not found.
```

I'm assuming there's some NSE magic at work here, but I haven't managed to `quo()` my way out of this. I did look at the `quo()`s of testframe2 and 3 (a debugging approach suggested in the [programming with dplyr vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)). I noticed they are the same:

```
testframe2quo <- quo(testframe %>% 
  mutate(
    fizzbuzz = case_when(
      y %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
      y %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
      y %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
      TRUE ~ as.character(y)
    )
  )
)

testframe3quo <- quo(testframe %>% 
  mutate(
    fizzbuzz = case_when(
      !!!(patterns)
    )
  )
)

 testframe2quo
<quosure: global>
~testframe %>% mutate(fizzbuzz = case_when(y%%35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz", 
    y%%5 == 0 ~ "fizz", y%%7 == 0 ~ "buzz", TRUE ~ as.character(y)))

testframe3quo
<quosure: global>
~testframe %>% mutate(fizzbuzz = case_when(y%%35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz", 
    y%%5 == 0 ~ "fizz", y%%7 == 0 ~ "buzz", TRUE ~ as.character(y)))
```

all of which brings me back to my question:
Can you use `!!!` splicing and a list input for `case_when` inside of a `mutate`, and how?

Comment: Your code for testframe2 don't throw an error because `as.character(x)` is evaluating `x` in your global env (`x <- 1:50`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your cases in `exprs` instead of `list` and use the prefix `.data`

```
patterns <- rlang::exprs(
  .data$y %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  .data$y %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  .data$y %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ as.character(.data$y)
)

mutate(testframe, fizzbuzz = case_when(!!! patterns))
```