# How can I use if statement in R with multi condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I'm new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I have a question about `if()` statements.

My data looks like:

```
Var1  Var2
4     2
6     2
5     1
3     3
2     1
```

I want to create a new variable called `Var3`. Something like

```
if Var2 = 1 then do; Var3 = Var1*30; end; else;
if Var2 = 2 then do; Var3 = Var1*4; end; else;
if Var2 = 3 then do; Var3 = Var1*1; end; else;
```

Any help to create the code will be appreciated.

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` is great for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649533/case-when-in-mutate-pipe

Comment: Case-when logic is good if you have complicated expressions, but R also allows you to avoid step-by-painstaking-step expressions. For instance, this is essentially a look-up table in this example - e.g. `dat$Var1 * c(30, 4, 1)[dat$Var2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) switch** Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end try using `switch` as shown here. No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * sapply(Var2, switch, 30, 4, 1))
```

giving:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    4    2   16
2    6    2   24
3    5    1  150
4    3    3    3
5    2    1   60
```

See `?switch` for more information.

**2) arithmetic** Another approach is to use an arithmetic statement that evaluates to the desired value.  This also uses no packages.

```
transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * ((Var2 == 1) * 30 + (Var2 == 2) * 4 + (Var2 == 3) * 1))
```

**2a)** A variation of this is:

```
transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * outer(Var2, 1:3, "==") %*% c(30, 4, 1))
```

**3) subscripting** This also works:

```
transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * c(30, 4, 1)[Var2])
```

**4) factor** Another approach is to create a factor and then convert that back to numeric:

```
transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * as.numeric(as.character(factor(Var2, labels = c(30, 4, 1)))))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Var1  Var2
4     2
6     2
5     1
3     3
2     1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The method you used on 2) arithmetic worked very well. I just faced one issue which is I couldn't find Var3 on the dataset. I tried to use the following  ```DF$SKM <- transform(DF, Var3 = Var1 * ((Var2 == 1) * 30 + (Var2 == 2) * 4 + (Var2 == 3) * 1))```  I couldn't find Var3. Is there a way to make the new variable part of the dataset

Comment: You need `DF <- transform(...`  or you can give it another name so that you don't overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0):

In syntax similar to what you listed:

```
DF$Var3 = with(DF,
  ifelse(Var2 == 1, Var1 * 30,
    ifelse(Var2 == 2, Var1 * 4, 
      ifelse(Var2 == 3, Var1, NA))))
```

But other methods will be faster to write and faster to run, once you get the hang of them.